# Condition Joins With many to many relationships

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I am working claims data and repricing the claims according to a different fee schedule.  So I have two tables.  The claims and fschedule. In this case, the repricing boils down to CPT_Code and Modifier. So I am conditionally joining them on

```
claims.CPT = fschedule.CPT 
AND 
claims.mod = fschedule.mod
```

Here is how the fschedule looks:

```
CPT || Modifier || Price

77325   ||   26 || 73.25

77325   ||   TC || 52.77

77325   ||   XX || 101.21 

77333   ||   XX || 12.31
```

However, my problem is that claims table may have:

```
CPT   || Modifier
77333 || TC
```

But the fschedule may have 77333 but not with a TC or 26 only XX. So I want the tables to join on both

```
claims.CPT = fschedule.CPT 
AND 
claims.mod = f.schedule.mod
```

but if there is no match in the fschedule then I want it to match when fschedule modifier XX

I am trying to conditionally join the two tables using case statements.

```
FROM
claims as c
LEFT JOIN
fschedule as f
ON
CASE WHEN c.mod IN ('TC','26') THEN
                                   CASE WHEN f.mod IN ('TC','26') AND c.cpt= f.cpt AND c.mod = f.mod THEN c.cpt = f.cpt AND c.mod = f.mod
                                        WHEN f.mod NOT IN ('TC','26') AND c.cpt= f.cpt AND c.mod <> f.mod THEN c.cpt = f.cpt AND c.mod <> f.mod
                                         END

WHEN c.mod NOT IN ('TC','26') AND f.mod NOT IN ('TC','26') THEN c.cpt = f.cpt AND c.mod = f.mod 
END;
```

I need to use a conditional left join like:

```
Claims as c
LEFT JOIN
fschedule as f
ON
c.CPT = f.CPT
AND
c.mod = f.mod
```

However, if the claims table has:

```
CPT   || Modifier || Paid
77333 || TC       || 7.88
```

But the fschedule only has:

```
CPT   || Modifier || Price
77333 || XX       || 12.31
```

I need the claims table to still output the price of 12.31 found in the fschedule table.  The XX modifier means no modifier exists.

Claims table before joining it to the fschedule table has 22,124 rows of data. After joining them with my current code the table outputs 25,283 rows of data. I need the output to stay 22,124.

In short, I need the two tables to join together on both:

```
c.cpt = f.cpt
AND
c.mod = f.mod
```

but if the claims table has a CPT code and modifier, but the fschedule only has the CPT code and no modifier match, then I need to force the fschedule to output the the price with the modifier XX since it does not have TC or 26 modifier.

Thank you for your help.

*************Updated issue**************

Claims table:

```
CPT   || Mod || Paid

77067 || TC  || 83.10
```

Fees Table

```
CPT   || Mod || Price
77067 || 26  || 76.23
77067 || XX  || 103.01
```

So even though the claims table has a modifier TC but fees table has the code but not the modifier, I still want it to connect on the claims table using the fees table when the modifier = XX.  So I would want the end result looking like:

```
CPT   || Mod  || Paid  || Fees_Price || Fees_Mod
77067 || TC   || 83.10 || 103.01     || XX
```

As of right now this is the output:

```
CPT   || Mod  || Paid  || Fees_Price || Fees_Mod
77067 || TC   || 83.10 ||            ||
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler ON condition can do the trick:

`ON (c.CPT = f.CPT AND c.mod = f.mod) OR (c.CPT = f.CPT AND f.mod ='xx' AND f.CPT NOT IN (SELECT CPT FROM Fees WHERE mod<>'xx'))`

Comment: The code is definitely cleaner. But the assumption is false because after connecting the tables on this the rows of data increases.

Comment: This is definitely getting better. Thank you so much! But I updated my post near the bottom to help explain the minor issue that still remains.